# Concatenate fields from one column in a Microsoft Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, concatenation, ms-access-2010

I would like to concatenate fields from one column in a query. My table in Microsoft Access look like this:

```
| Cluster1  |  Cluster2  |  Reason   |
|-----------|------------|-----------|
| Cluster A | Cluster A1 | Reason 1  |
| Cluster A | Cluster A1 | Reason 2  |
| Cluster A | Cluster A2 | Reason 3  |
| Cluster A | Cluster A2 | Reason 4  |
| Cluster B | Cluster B1 | Reason 5  |
| Cluster B | Cluster B1 | Reason 6  |
| Cluster B | Cluster B1 | Reason 7  |
| Cluster B | Cluster B1 | Reason 8  |
| Cluster B | Cluster B1 | Reason 9  |
| Cluster B | Cluster B2 | Reason 10 |
```

The result I want to achieve in a query should look like this:

```
| Cluster1  |  Cluster2  |                   Reason                     |
|-----------|------------|----------------------------------------------|
| Cluster A | Cluster A1 | Reason1,Reason 2                             |
| Cluster A | Cluster A2 | Reason3,Reason 4                             |
| Cluster B | Cluster B1 | Reason 5,Reason 6,Reason 7,Reason 8,Reason 9 |
| Cluster B | Cluster B2 | Reason 10                                    |
```

I found already some similar questions, but they were more simple and I could unfortunately not adjust them to my case. I learned that I have to use a Concatenate VBA code by Allen Browne, and with that I could Imitate an easier example.

---

The solution of Zacharey work very well will my test data, but when I try to use it with my real data, which have close to 200.000 records with 5000 main Cluster (cluster1) , it never ends to calculate. Only when I extremely reduce the volume of data rows filtering by only one letter of the alphabet (like A*) I get after 2-4 hours a result. Currently I started to run it manually by each main cluster and to add it to a table, but seems not to be efficient. Do you have an idea how I could speed that up. I assume creating a filter (roughly 5000 with circa 50 data rows each) which process each main cluster one by one and then running the query, or creating a temp table 5000 times and run then the query 5000 times with 50 rows only would speed up the processing, but I never did something like that. Do you have an example code which I could try to adjust to my need ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Distinct
    table.Cluster1,
    table.Cluster2,
    ConcatRelated("Reason", "table", "Cluster1=""" & [Cluster1] & """ and Cluster2=""" & [Cluster2] & """") AS Reasons
FROM table;
```

Does this work for you? You do in fact need to use ConcatRelated from Allen Browne

Comment: Dear Zacharey,

Many thanks to you ! It work very well ! I am very happy with the solution you provided me.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution:

## MySQL Solution

In MySQL you can use the function `GROUP_CONCAT` to achieve this easily. The code for that is presented bellow:

```
select `Cluster 1`, `Cluster 2`, GROUP_CONCAT(`Reason`) as Reason
from test
group by `Cluster 1`, `Cluster 2`
```

And here you can access a link to the [fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/693862/1) that illustrate it.

## How to use in Access

In access you don't have this function naturally, but as you wrote in your question, someone named Allen Browne made a custom function to achieve this same result ([link](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html)).

In the [link](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) you can read a clear way to implement it in the section `How to use the function`. You just have to add a module with the presented function, compile and use it.

#### Equivalent Code in Access

I believe that the code in MySQL translated to the same solution in MS Access would be:

```
SELECT test.[﻿Custer 1], test.[Cluster 2], ConcatRelated("Reason","test", "test.[﻿Custer 1]&test.[Cluster 2] = """ & test.[﻿Custer 1]&test.[Cluster 2] & """") AS Reason
FROM test
GROUP BY test.[﻿Custer 1], test.[Cluster 2];
```

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by the MySQL references, this appears to be a simple case of just "Use the Allen Browne function."

Comment: Dear Arnold,

many thanks for your answer and your effort. Highly appreciated.

Best regards, Dieter